Error installing Selenium with pip : Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully
I'm trying to install Selenium package for python with pip, but keep getting this error when 'Getting requirements to build wheel'.
PS C:\Users\Oisin\repositories\Scraper> python .\scrapeData.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Oisin\repositories\Scraper\scrapeData.py", line 7, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
PS C:\Users\Oisin\repositories\Scraper> python -m pip install selenium
Collecting selenium
  Using cached selenium-4.21.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.26 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from urllib3[socks]<3,>=1.26->selenium) (2.2.1)
Collecting trio~=0.17 (from selenium)
  Using cached trio-0.25.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.7 kB)
Collecting trio-websocket~=0.9 (from selenium)
  Using cached trio_websocket-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2021.10.8 in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from selenium) (2024.2.2)
Collecting typing_extensions>=4.9.0 (from selenium)
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.11.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting attrs>=23.2.0 (from trio~=0.17->selenium)
  Using cached attrs-23.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
Collecting sortedcontainers (from trio~=0.17->selenium)
  Using cached sortedcontainers-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (from trio~=0.17->selenium) (3.7)
Collecting outcome (from trio~=0.17->selenium)
  Using cached outcome-1.3.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Collecting sniffio>=1.3.0 (from trio~=0.17->selenium)
  Using cached sniffio-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.14 (from trio~=0.17->selenium)
  Using cached cffi-1.16.0.tar.gz (512 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Oisin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f8yun7ic\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\Oisin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f8yun7ic\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Oisin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f8yun7ic\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 126, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 105, in uses_msvc
        File "C:\Users\Oisin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f8yun7ic\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 220, in try_compile
          self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "C:\Users\Oisin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f8yun7ic\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "C:\Users\Oisin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f8yun7ic\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 343, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\Oisin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f8yun7ic\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 246, in initialize
          raise DistutilsPlatformError(
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
PS C:\Users\Oisin\repositories\Scraper>

I tried checking out this directory C:\Users\Oisin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f8yun7ic\ but it doesn't exist, the only similar directory there is pip-uninstall-tk4rop8y
I've tried all sorts of similar commands instead of python -m pip install selenium, i did pip install selenium / python3 -m pip install selenium / pip3 install selenium etc. all same result.
Tried updating pip to no avail python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip.
python --version

Python 3.10.11

python -m pip --version

pip 24.0 from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

Not sure where to go from here other than reinstalling python and pip...

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Seems a problem related to versions. I suggest you to create a separated pyhon environment for your project to avoid those incompatibilities.
1. Create a new environment with python 3.11
I suppose you a re Windows 11, so open a git bash and execute the following to create a new env and activate it
conda create -n myproject python=3.11
conda activate myenv
pip install selenium

2. Tes your env in a notebook
Then open anaconda navigator, select this new environment, and launch a notebook. It should now work.
